# Create directory in .spec file for packages - with version and name

Tags: linux, bash, rpm, specifications

I am trying to "instal" different version of a library side by side. When installing different version of the package. So by the .spec file for the package, I wish to create a directory in /usr/lib/secret/ and in /usr/include/secret, this directory should have the name of the library (let us say random) and the version name (let us say 0_1) so the directory name should be: random_0_1.
How can I do that with mkdir or another command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the name and version (specified by `Name:` and `Version:`, respectively, in the spec file) using `%{name}` and `%{version}`:

```
mkdir /usr/lib/secret/%{name}_%{version}
mkdir /usr/include/secret/%{name}_%{version}
```

Comment: What about in for instance if[ ! -d "$/usr/lib/secret/" ]; ?

Comment: What about it? You can use `%{name}` anywhere you like, since `rpmbuild` will expand it prior to passing any code to the shell. As long as the expansion results in valid shell code, you're fine.

Comment: so example if[ ! -d "$usr/lib/secret/%{name}_%{version}" ]; would work ?